# How to loop through folders to find the file and move the file to other folder

Tags: windows-shell

I want to move the files to the respective folders using batch file.
Someone please help as i am new to scripting.

I have folder hiererchy as below

```
Root
  Root1
     Doc2012.txt
     Doc2013.txt
     Doc2012.txt
  Root2
     Doc2012.txt
     Doc2013.txt
     Doc2012.txt
  Root3
     Doc2012.txt
     Doc2013.txt
     Doc2012.txt
```

Then i have another 2 folder 2012,2013..i want to move the file from root1,root2,root3 which contains  2012 in their name to folder->2012 and the file which contains 2013 in their names to Folder->2013

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

- create file move2012.cmd in the root of your hiererchy,
- put this line in move2012.cmd (it moves all files with '2012' in name to directory 2012):

  for /r . %%i in (****2012****) do move %%i 2012
- run move2012.cmd

If it is what you want, now it is easy to extend this cmd file for 2011, 2013 etc.